# Can I get the average value for each hour in Excel? Different amount of data for each hour

Tags: excel, average

I have about 160k rows of data which consists of temperatures and flow rates. I need to get it down to being a bit more manageable. I would like to have an average temperature and flow rate each hour instead of several values each minute. I'm not much of a programmer but I don't think this would be a problem if it were the case that I had the same amount of measurements each hour, which is not the case. Each hour has between 200-400 data points and I'm not sure how I would go about this problem. The output I want is something like 
date - hr - average1 - average 2 ... and so on.

[How the sheet looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZPSM.png)

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to go about this?

Sincerely,

Comment: It sounds as if you could use a pivot table but would need to get the date and hour in separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it looks in a pivot table. I've put in some dummy data which has two different days and two different times to test it.

To get the date without the time I've used

```
=floor(B2,1)
```

because date-times are stored as decimal numbers where the whole number part contains the date and the fraction part contains the time.

To get the hour I've just used

```
=hour(B2)
```

My test data looks like this

[image]

and the resulting pivot table looks like this

[image]

I had to use Value Field Settings and Number Format to tidy up the formatting of the date and average columns.

Comment: Thank you, will try this out, it looks like it's exactly what I need!